# Saving Data from related tables in Winforms

Tags: c#

I can't seem to 'save' data from a Winforms app to my SQL Server Compact edition database. When I click save, it just saves the data from one table, not all of them.  I used the drag/drop method to add fields from different tables to save to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post your code so we can try and help you?!

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code and give more details on the structure of the tables and their relationships?

Answer (score 0):

As a blind guess (since you provided no code): try to look at this article, with special attention to point 3) Insert a New Category and Two New Products into the Database: [using linq to sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).